# Searching a CSV with PHP

Tags: php, csv, php5

Given a string, I've done the below to search a CSV for a keyword and display the row if it's found

```
<?php 
$ch = fopen("test.csv", "r");
$header_row = fgetcsv($ch);

/* This will loop through all the rows until it reaches the end */
while(($row = fgetcsv($ch)) !== FALSE) {
    $cols = array($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3]);
    if (in_array("text", $cols)) {
        echo '<div>'.$row[0].' | '.$row[1].' | '.$row[2].' | '.$row[3].' </div>';
    }
?>
```

I'm worried it's not best optimised for my needs, especially as the search is not regex'd and its assuming a X number of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Useless transformation**

Since `fgetcsv()` returns an *indexed* array, the statement

`$cols = array($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3]);`

is totally useless: it results in `$cols` which is exactly the same as `$row`.

**Using any number of columns**

BTW, the above already answers part of your concern, regarding:

> its assuming a X number of columns

Directly working with `$rows` you keep all original columns.

The last part is that this statement:

`echo '<div>'.$row[0].' | '.$row[1].' | '.$row[2].' | '.$row[3].' </div>';`

can be replaced by:

`echo '<div>' . implode(' | ', $row) . ' </div>';`

Then, again, you'll get the exact content, whatever is the number of columns.

So your whole code can be reduced like this:

```
$ch = fopen("test.csv", "r");
$header_row = fgetcsv($ch);

/* This will loop through all the rows until it reaches the end */
while($row = fgetcsv($ch)) {
    if (in_array("text", $row)) {
        echo '<div>' . implode(' | ', $row) . ' </div>';
    }
}
```

NOTE: `if (in_array("text", $cols))` is enough and you don't need to look for `FALSE`, since `fgetcsv()` doesn't return falsy value other than `FALSE` itself.

Any not empty content is obviously not `FALSE`, and an empty line returns `[0 => null]`, as stated by [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

> A blank line in a CSV file will be returned as an array comprising a single null field, and will not be treated as an error.

**Using regexes**

There is no need to use regexes: you're looking for a unique precise value, so in your case it'll be overkill!

It might not be the same if, for example, you wanted to find "text" even if it's *only part* of one (or more) column content.

Then you should do something like this:

`if (preg_match('/text/', implode('', $row)))`

Here we had to turn `$row` content into a string before applying the pattern.
But this can be improved in the context of your snippet: do `implode()` only once, so it will be alredy done for the `echo`, while the additional `|` doesn't matter for the `preg_match`.

This way, it'll result in:

```
while($row = fgetcsv($ch)) {
    if (preg_match('/text/', $row = implode(' | ', $row))) {
        echo '<div>' . $row . ' </div>';
    }
}
```